# How to call a function using variable in javascript without using window?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

Suppose there is a function (from a module) named `fiveStar` and I want to call it using a variable,

For e.g using `window`, I could do this:

```
const num = 'five';
const functionName = `${num}Star';
window[functionName]();
```

Is there any other way I could do this without using `window`?

Comment: Create an object or class with the methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an object to group functions together.

```
const myModule = {
   fiveStar: ()=>{}
   //other methods...
};
const num = 'five';
const functionName = `${num}Star`;
myModule[functionName]();
```

Answer (score 0):

should work on any object with a function declared in it

### Example:

```js
let obj = {
  fiveStar: () => {
    console.log('called me')
  }
}

let str = 'fiveStar'
obj[str]()
```